# React returns several errors when I import fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am building a simple app using React.
The app works fine without any issue until I import fetch.

Here is the code I ran:

**App.js**

```
import CountryBtn from './components/CountryBtn.js'
import WeatherIcon from './components/WeatherIcon.js'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'


const App = () => {
  return (
  <>
  <div id='WeatherForm'>
    <div id='CountryBtnGroup'>
    <CountryBtn name='Seoul' />
    <CountryBtn name='Moscow' />
    </div>
    <div id='WeatherToday'>
      <h2>Today</h2>
      <div id='TemperatureToday'><WeatherIcon type='Today' /><h2>15℃</h2></div>
    </div>
    <div id='WeatherOtherDay'>
      <div id='Today+1' className='AnotherDay'>
        <h2>AnotherDay</h2>
        <div className='TemperatureAnother'><WeatherIcon type='AnotherDay' /><h2>14℃</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div id='Today+2' className='AnotherDay'>
        <h2>AnotherDay</h2>
        <div className='TemperatureAnother'><WeatherIcon type='AnotherDay' /><h2>14℃</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div id='Today+3' className='AnotherDay'>
        <h2>AnotherDay</h2>
        <div className='TemperatureAnother'><WeatherIcon type='AnotherDay' /><h2>14℃</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div id='Today+4' className='AnotherDay'>
        <h2>AnotherDay</h2>
        <div className='TemperatureAnother'><WeatherIcon type='AnotherDay' /><h2>14℃</h2></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Some of the errors returned are:

[image]

What I tried to resolve the errors are:

1. Trying to substitute fetch with axios. But it seems to return the same errors.
2. Adding `experiments: {   topLevelAwait: true }` to the module.exports object in webpack.config.js file.

I made a research in google but I could not find any solution to fix this issue. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. It seems like node-fetch packages that have higher versions than `node-fetch@2.x.x` are not compatible with React. So I downgraded the node-fetch package into `node-fetch@2.6.1`. Now the app runs well without any issue!

I found the solution at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/33982.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the StackOverflow community, I suggest using Axios which is a tool that can help you connect to APIs.

Here is an implementation example:

```js
import Axios from 'axios'; 

// Get request 
function fetch(){ 
  Axios.get("https://exmaple.com").then((response) => { 
    console.log(response)l // The response of the API 
  }) 
}

// Post request 
function post(){ 
  Axios.post("https://exmaple.com", {foo: "bar", foofoo: "barbar"}).then((response) => { 
    console.log(response) // The response from the server. 
 }) 
}
```

Link: https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score -1):

you can use fetch API (doesn't require any import) / axios instead of node-fetch package for a basic react application.

Sharing complete code of where fetch method is used will be helpful.

fetch API : [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#syntax)